# Spring MVC; error messages of validation form not being displayed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I have built a form for login. I've read about validations with spring mvc following a tutorial.

The form is blank & doesn't pass values, however it doesn't show any error messages.

This is my code for the controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView login() {
    return new ModelAndView("login", "user", new UserModel());
    }

    @RequestMapping("/submitLogin")
    public ModelAndView submitLogin(@Valid UserModel user, BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("user", user);
        model.setViewName(result.hasErrors() ? "login" : "index");
        return model;
    }
}
```

This is my model:

```
@Data
public class UserModel {
    @NotBlank(message = "The field login name is required")
    private String login;
    @NotBlank(message = "The field password is required")
    private String password;    
}
```

And this is my form:

```
<mvc:form modelAttribute="user" class="col s12" action="/submitLogin" method="POST">
    <div class="container login-form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <mvc:input path="login" id="userName" type="text" class="validate" />
                <mvc:label path="login" for="userName">Login name</mvc:label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <mvc:errors path="login" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <mvc:input path="password" id="password" type="password" class="validate" />
                <mvc:label path="password" for="password">Password</mvc:label>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <mvc:errors path="password" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light pulse green" value="Entrar"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</mvc:form>
```

Did I miss any configuration on spring boot or annotation?